# Filters in pivoted react-table

Tags: reactjs, filter, react-table

I am using react-table in order to render a table that is pivoted and aggregated.
However, filters are no longer working: every time I filter, no rows are returned. These same filters were working perfectly well before I added the pivoting and aggregation.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: We need code to help you...

Answer (score 2):

**This answer concerns react-table [v6](https://github.com/tannerlinsley/react-table/tree/v6), not [v7](https://github.com/tannerlinsley/react-table).**
(it is unclear from the question which version is used by OP but I find little information regarding this issue for v6 so I am posting what I see)

If you wish to filter on rows that have been aggregated (ie. in a table with columns A and B, where A is the pivot and B is aggregated, whilst you want to filter on column B) I found that I can use the `row._subRows` value.

I have a column that specifies its aggregation (in other words it specifies what is shown for that column of a row which is collapsed by the pivot). I realized that the standard `filterMethod` for the column receives the aggregated row with this different 'aggregate' value. If I return `false` for this row in the `filterMethod` (since the aggregated value is not what I am trying to filter, rather the distinct values are) the filter method rejects all of the "sub rows" under the wing of this aggregation because it is rejecting the pivoted row.

The solution to this is to not throw out a pivoted row with sub rows if you intend to filter by them. (they are then passed to the `filterMethod` after the aggregated row)

The way I now filter these rows that get aggregated is if `row._subRows` is `undefined`, then I know I am dealing with an "un aggregated row" and simply filter as usual. Otherwise (when `row._subRows` is **not** `undefined`) then I know I am dealing with the top level aggregated row, and I return `true` so the sub rows get passed to the `filterMethod`. Like so:

```js
filterMethod: (filter, row) => {
    if (row._subRows === undefined) {
      return row[filter.id].toLowerCase().includes(filter.value.toLowerCase())
    } else {
      return true;
    }
```

Two things to note are:

1. When you filter the rows will still all collapse on their pivots, but when you expand them the values will be limited by your filter. Collapsing is a separate issue which I do not feel confident addressing.
2. You may want to not include the aggregate rows that have no subrows which match your filter. I have not thoroughly tested this, but my current solution probably retains these rows even if no subrow matches, since they are flagged as true in the filtering. One way to get around this may be to check the actual value of `_subRows` and only return `true` if you know there are subrows you want to show.

Please be wary of other filtering aspects of react-table v6 and how they relate to what I said here and my limited understanding.

Answer (score 1):

When aggregating/pivoting, the values provided to the `filterMethod` are slightly varied.

I was using Fuse.js and `filterAll={true}` to provide fuzzy filtering on some fields and had to update the function to include `_pivotVal` as part of the check for the filtering to work.

```
filterMethod: (filter, rows) => {
    var fuse = new Fuse(rows, { keys: [ filter.id, "_pivotVal" ]});
    var res = fuse.search(filter.value);
    return res;
}
```